# html5 video playlist has gaps between videos

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a playlist using the HTML5 `<video>` tag and the onended trigger.

The playlist works, videos get played one after another, but the problem is that there is a minor gap between 2 videos played.

Its not a seamless continuous play. What can I do to fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
<video id="vd" style=" width: 480px; height: 360px; " autoplay controls 
src="vid/0006v.mp4" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var vf=[ "0006v", "0007v", "0008v", "0009v", "0010v" ];
var c=0;
v=document.getElementById("vd");
v.onended=function()
{
  ++c;
  if( c >= vf.length ){ c=0; }
  v.src= "vid/"+ vf[c]+ ".mp4";
};
</script>
```

Below is the player demo.
Each video is of 1 minute duration, about 5 loaded in the playlist.

The gap appears when video number one ends after 1 minute and second video starts, and so on...

http://13pp.co.uk/play.php

Comment: it buffers the video when the new video is being played and thats obvious

Comment: So what can I do to pre-load the video file so that this buffering does not occurs?

Comment: as you can see in your code the src is set once the last video is ended. so it would be nice if you just animate the transition so that it looks natural and more lively else its not possible to have two src set on same video tag. what you can do is to create a custom html5 video player like this github repo => https://github.com/sampotts/plyr

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the next video only starts downloading when the previous video ends. Here's my solution:

Have two `<video>` elements, one visible and one hidden. Set the `src` attribute of the first to the first video URL. When the first `<video>` element is almost done playing, set the `src` attribute of the second to the second video and call `video2.load()`, but don't start playing right away. When the first `<video>` element is done playing, make the first invisible, make the second visible and start playing the second. Then use the first to play the third video, the second to play the fourth, etc...